# Strange prompt on Windows logon, "Restore items from your last session?" - malware?

Tags: windows, boot, malware

Sometimes, over the last week or so, I am starting to see a strange dialog during Windows 10 logon.

[image]

I have run a Malwarebytes scan and nothing was found. Nevertheless this remains a concern owing to the complete lack of any source identifier to say what app or process is putting up this dialog.

Like most people I guess, I have numerous things configured to run at logon, which makes it hard to know where this is coming from, but surely this must be some kind of malware? All the dialogs I've ever seen include something to identify the source of the prompt, such as an app or a Windows process.

I started to wonder if it was from an Outlook 365 subscription update at one point... but a dialog with these fundamental defects?

- No app identifer, and
- Wrong icon (Info icon for a question)

I'm thinking surely Microsoft wouldn't release something that bad, which leads me to conclude it can't be Windows or a Microsoft app?

Comment: Try a Full Scan with Windows Defender to see if it picks up and cleans up more.  Make a new , test, Windows User Profile. Log into the new Windows Profile and test. This issue could possibly be a damaged Profile.

Comment: Maybe track it down using task manager when the dialog box is present.

Comment: @John I'll try the full Defender scan now.

Comment: @Moab I thought that too, as I've found things that way before when the dialog title appears in Task Manager, but for this one it didn't seem to show. I'll check again next time it happens.